# Using ed line editor for matching lines with a regular expression

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, ed

i  am trying  to use `ed` command in with  regular expressions

> participants.txt

```
#Team:Volgnummer:Nationaliteit:Auto:Klasse
DECONINCK Nico - DECONNINCK Gregory:0:B/B:OPEL Kadett:1A
DECONINCK Harry - Verhelst Jos:1:B/B:OPEL Kadett:1A
DEBRUYNE Jurgen - DERIEMAEKER Jolien :2:B/B :LADA Samara :1A
ROMMELAERE Michel - DEVOS Ingrid :3:B/B :TOYOTA Corolla :1A
DIERCKX Guy - NIETVELT Werner :4:B/B :TOYOTA Corolla :1A
HAMIAUX Bjorn -:5:B/ :HONDA Civic :1A
VAN GRASDORFF David - BRAEM Theo :6:B/B :HONDA Civic :1A
```

if i run the `ed -s participants.txt` in bash shell , then type a regular expression for ex `^D.*A$` . i got `?`

what is the wrong with my expression .

Comment: `^D.*A$` isn't an ed command. Read the GNU ed manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to use the [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Regular-expressions) in `ed`? You need to define it in the `g/<re>/` syntax for it to work, e.g. the following could work

```sh
ed -s participants.txt <<< 'g/^D.*A/'
```